# How do i stop a countdown timer when in a new activity

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I've implemented a countdown timer into a game that I am currently doing, so when the counter goes to 0 it takes you back to the beginning of the activity, but if a question is answered correctly before the time ends and starts a new activity the timer still continues and takes me back to the beginning. So I am wondering what I need to do in order to rectify this so that the timer stops when starting a new activity. I am very new to all this and learning as I go.

```
      {

    context = this;


    new CountDownTimer(+16000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            TextView variable = (countdownText);
            final int counter = Main1Activity.this.counter;
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(counter +15));
            Main1Activity.this.counter--;
            if(countdownTimer != null) countdownTimer.cancel();

        }


        public void onFinish() {
            // Here do what you like...
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    }.start();

}
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: your code sample is not clear, add the program that you are running in your machine

Comment: why don’t you just stop it before the startActivity line?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily overcome the difficulty using the lifecycle functions of the activity where the timer is running. All you have to do is stop the timer when the activity is paused or destroyed.

Hence you could do something like the following.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
   if(countDownTimer != null) countDownTimer.cancel();
}
```

To understand the activity lifecycle, please look into [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) here.

Comment: This doesn't work. I tried everything but countdowntimer runs double time when the activity was finished and started again.